# Show an image in a panel/window

Tags: python, scripting, interface, add-on

A typical blender panel looks like this:

[image]

We have a layout object, and we typically add stuff to it. My add-on lets user select from many garments, and for that, I need to be able to show the garment images clearly. So I can't use a button icon, since the user won't be able to see the garment properly when it is icon-size.

So I need to show an image in the panel whose size I can set. Is there a way to add an image like that to the layout of the panel?

Comment: Yes, I know it's a duplicate. But there are no answers or recent activity on that question hence asked a new one

Comment: There is an answer..? Without an answer, it's not possible to close another question as a duplicate of it.